# Weak Wireless Signal - Atheros ar5008x drops connection

Tags: wireless, atheros, signal

I'm dualbooting Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows Vista and while Vista handles the signal perfectly (4 or 5 bars out of 5 and never drops) Ubuntu shows 1 or 2 bars and drops the signal constantly if the laptop is out of 3-4m range.

I already tried to google ar5008x linux driver but no luck so far. I'm a new linux user and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In your router settings, probably the "Advanced" tab, you can set the **Beacon Interval**. The default is 100, you could reduce it to like 25 and hopefully the connection will not be dropped.